# Is Syncadapter called in phone's sleep mode?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I wonder if syncadapter in Android is called even if the phone is in sleep mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer the question myself. Yes, syncadapter is called even if the pnone is in sleep mode.